# css issue with float content

Tags: css

I need to move up the fourth column right beneath the first column. Is there any possibility to do this in css?

```
<body>
    <div class="fleft">1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="fleft">2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</div>
    <div class="fleft">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
    <div class="fleft">4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</div>
    <div class="fleft">5 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body  { width:600px;}
.fleft{ float:left; width:200px;}
​
```

Please refer the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9xbGC/

Comment: fiddles can go down provide sth in your question as well for future children

Comment: If the amount of columns is known before the template is parsed you can make 3 columns to fit the items in. But you could still come up with some columns becoming much higher than the others. So masonry is probably still the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Given your original structure - No there isn't (with sole css and without dirty hacks). The fourth column has to obey the height of the third one.

Perhaps this jQuery Plugin can help you:

http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

Only way you can do it with pure CSS is to have 3 columns and split your content up between them.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this using position absolute and setting top and left for each , but you should do this using javascript if you don't know height of each

or you can use jquery plugin: http://www.wookmark.com/jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

No, only if you could rely on a specific height of the first div.

```
#div4{
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with floating, since float only adjusts the flow of elements, not their order.
You may go for absolute/relative positioning, javasscript.

Answer (score 0):

Specify widths of the divs so that the 4th div would fit between the first and third divs, and then when you float the 4th collumn left it should sit right.

Edit:
You can also Use the awesome grid system that comes with Twitter Bootstrap, it's very useful and can sort out a serious amount of layout issues.
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/